# How can I lock checkbox once someone ticked in Google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have added check box in Column AW. How can lock the response (If some one click on the check box) it will be protected/locked?

[image]

Please help with the simple way because I am new in Google app script

Answer (score 1):

#### Once checked stays checked

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast('Entry');
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  //sh.getRange("A1").setValue(JSON.stringify(e));
  if(sh.getName() == "Sheet0" && e.range.columnStart == 49 && e.range.rowStart > 1 && e.value == "FALSE" ) {
    //e.source.toast('Flag1')
    if(e.oldValue == "true")e.range.setValue("TRUE");
  }
}
```

Comment: It is not working for me could you please help

Comment: Did you change sheet name?

Comment: Where I need to change the Sheet name please help I am very new in App script

Comment: Where it says "Sheet0"